# Given $N$ samples from $p(x|y=y_0)$ how can I infer $y_0$?

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, conditioning

I have $N$ samples $x_i \sim p(x|y)$ for $y = y_0$.
I don't know apriori what $y_0$ is but I know its a fixed value. 
I do not have the analytic form of $p(x|y)$, $p(y|x)$, $p(x,y)$.
Instead I have discrete probability lookup tables(that I can interpolate).

How can I now infer $y_0$?

I originally thought I could just sample $y_i \sim p(y|x=x_i)$ and then find
the mean of $y_i$ but that is not working.

What is the correct way of approaching this?

Comment: Do you know the form of $p(x|y)$ or do you just have samples drawn from that distribution?

Comment: I have the form of $p(x|y)$ in the above example. But I would prefer to compute the result without knowing it.

Comment: You have asked "how do I perform statistical inference?" The answer requires a textbook-length treatise. I would guess your problem has something to do with conditionally Normal distributions, but because the details are buried in code, only people familiar with Matlab--and with the willingness to dig through the code to find the key parts--will have that essential information. Please edit this question to provide the details of your setting: and then be prepared for the community to point out duplicate threads on estimating parameters of Normal distributions.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question. The specific scenario is that I dont have analytic forms for my probabilities. Instead I have lookup tables. I do not know what the correct numerical approach is. Could I use Gibbs sampling to impute the values of y? EM? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you have tables that give various values of $y$ and for each such value they tabulate the probability distribution of $X|y$? Where do these tables come from? (Sometimes, information about the genesis of a table can lead to very accurate methods of interpolation or even to good analytic approximations of its entries.) Please be aware your use of the word "impute" (which refers to a process of recovering missing values of the $x_i$) conflicts with the description of your data: according to it, the unknown value $y_0$ is a *parameter* and your task is to *estimate* it.

Comment: The tables come from an empirical measurement. They are essentially histograms. To get an analytic approximation to the pdfs I could perform kernel density estimation. I understand your resistance to the word impute. I cant edit the comment though. I am somewhat surprised that there is no immediate answer to my problem even if it involves some complicated sampling method.

Comment: Do you have lookup tables as a function of both x and y, or just y? Could you mock-up an example? It's just not clear what your set-up is.

Comment: There are many immediate answers to your question--but it is beginning to sound like they won't address the problem you really have. Since your "tables" are actually data, you need to account for that fact in the procedure; it is not valid to treat them as if they were definite probability distributions. Why don't you start at the beginning and give us a full account of the data you have and what you are trying to find out?

Comment: @Max, if I did have the form of $p(x|y)$ what would the right direction be?

Comment: @twerdster If you had $p(x|y)$ you could use maximum likelihood to estimate $y_0$, the value of $y$ that maximizes the likelihood of observing the given sample.

Comment: @Max, I tried that and it worked i.e. $y_0$ = $argmax_y$ $\Sigma_i$ $log(p(x_i|y))$. Please can you specify it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Also, do you have any ideas regarding the scenario where $p(x|y)$ is not available or not easily available?